# Hibernate menu option not working, but s2disk works

Tags: linux-mint, swap, hibernate

I set up a swap partition on my computer so I could hibernate. It's twice as big as my RAM, and shows up in System Monitor. When I run `sudo s2disk`, my computer hibernates, and resumes successfully. when I press my power button (which brings up the Power Menu) and click Hibernate, the screen freezes, turns black, turns back on, then shuts down. It doesn't show any sign of resuming when I boot. Is there a way to edit the command the Hibernate button uses? Or fix the issue with the button?